# Why Rakudo Star for Windows still compiled/linked for exact FS location (c:\rakudo)?

Tags: raku, portable-applications, rakudo

And what should be done so Rakudo (Star) does not depend on the location in filesystem?

Answer (score 5):

### Update

Some time in 2019 Rakudo gained the ability to be relocatable. So there is now no technical limitation anymore.

As of today no installers that allow to choose the installation location have been provided yet though.

### Original answer

As it currently stands Rakudo depends on the absolute installation path in several places including the binaries. Rakudo Star must install to that exact location (*C:\rakudo*) because that path is compiled into the binaries.

Making Rakudo independent of its FS location (aka portable) is possible, but simply not yet implemented.

Answer (score 2):

It takes someone familiar with the Wix windows installer to change its XML config file.

https://github.com/rakudo/star/blob/master/tools/build/star-product.wxs#L6

Comment: It's forced to `C:\rakudo` because it was compiled to go into `C:\rakudo`. If you installed it elsewhere, it would still try to open files in `C:\rakudo`.

Comment: I got it, but what should be done to make all binaries and cmd/bat scripts independent from FS location in Rakudo distribution, like Strawberry Perl 5 do. After installation I can move Strawberry dir freely and need to change only environment variables since paths not compiled in files.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hack and not a real solution, but it's possible to create a junction or, if you don't have `C:` drive at all, use `subst` command to still make Rakudo work without really putting it under the hardcoded directory.